# Enlarging a Bitmap

Tags: java, android, image, bitmap, rescale

I would like to resize an image (Bitmap) with a minimum width and height and keep the ratio.

For now I tryed some methods but I didnt get a correct result.

The closest way was with this method:

```
Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmapToScale, newWidth, newHeight, false);
```

and there is the result:

**croped image**

[image: croped image]

The image is indeed resized but only the last column and row are dulicated to the end (right and bottom)

Do anyone as a good method to resize an image on Android ?

(PS: I can't use xml scale option cose I have to transform the image after the crop and neither Glide or picasso)

Comment: It's not issue with resize but certain operation over image make it distort at bottom.

Comment: @pskink no I can't, cose I need to transform my image after the crop

Comment: it's an imageview with a fitCenter scaletype, the crop is done programatically. The code I use: Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmapToScale, width * scaling, height * scaling, true); then : Bitmap.createBitmap(scaledBitmap, 0, 0, newWidth, newHeight);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Bitmap.createScaledBitmap` is the correct way to scale a bitmap. The result you are getting might be the result of improper implementation while displaying it. Such result usually occurs if you are using `BitmapShader`.

Comment: thanks for your answer but I dont use BitmapShader, and the image is displayd with glide 4.0:

I only do a 
Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmapToScale,  (int) (bitmapToScale.getWidth() * scaling), (int) (bitmapToScale.getHeight() * scaling), true);
for scaling, then :
        Bitmap.createBitmap(scaledBitmap, 0, 0, (int) newWidth, (int) newHeight);
to crop

Comment: You are right !
BitmapShader break my croped Image.
I didnt look at the good place
Thanks :)